# The space of continuous, bounded functions from a metric space $X$ to $\mathbb R$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

1. Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. We denote by $C_b(X;\mathbb{R})$ the space of continuous and
   bounded functions from $X$ into $\mathbb{R}$, equipped with the sup-norm metric. We define a
   mapping  $O: X \to C_b(X;\mathbb{R})$ as follows. Fix a point $x_0\in X$. Given $x\in X$, $O(x)$ is a function from $X$ into $\mathbb{R}$ such that
   $O(x)(y) = d(y, x)-d(y, x_0)$:
   Show the following.

   - $(i)$ $C_b(X;\mathbb{R})$ is a complete metric space.
   - $(ii)$ For each $x \in X$, the corresponding function $O(x): X \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and bounded.
   - $(iii)$ Mapping $x \mapsto O(x)$ yields an isometric embedding of $X$ into $C_b(X,\mathbb{R})$.
     Thus every metric space may be isometrically embedded into a complete metric space.

Comment: Why are you editing the question, its title, and proposing to edit my answer out as well?

Comment: @user63929, that is not how this site works. If you made a mistake by posting here, then now you know better.

Comment: @user63929: Maybe if you give a *reason*, it will be.

Comment: Self-vandalizing your question like this is **extremely disrepecful** to those who have taken time to answer. People are here and helping without any compensation, and you are showing very bad manners treating their help in this way.

Comment: @user58512: What what?

Comment: @user58512: What on earth are you talking about?

Answer (score 8):

- $(i)$ Take a Cauchy sequence $(f_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}\subseteq C_{b}(X;\mathbb{R})$ in the sup-norm $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$ and $\varepsilon>0$. Hence there exists $n_{\varepsilon}\in\mathbb{N}$ so that 
  \begin{equation*}
  |f_{n}(x)-f_{m}(x)|\leq \|f_{n}-f_{m}\|_{\infty}<\frac{\varepsilon}{3}
  \end{equation*}
  for all $n,m\geq n_{\varepsilon}$, which shows that $(f_{n}(x))_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ for every $x\in X$. Since $\mathbb{R}$ is complete, for every $x\in X$ there exists $f(x)\in \mathbb{R}$ so that $f_{n}(x)\to f(x)$. Since limits are unique in metric spaces, you may define a function $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ so that $x\mapsto f(x)$. Now $f$ is the point-wise limit of $f_{n}$. We show that $\|f_{n}-f \|_{\infty}\to 0$ and $f\in C_{b}(X;\mathbb{R})$. Fix $x\in X$. Now there exists $n_{0}\in \mathbb{N}$ so that $|f_{n}(x)-f(x)|<\frac{\varepsilon}{3}$ for all $n\geq n_{0}$.. Thus for every $n\geq n_{1}:=\max\{n_{\varepsilon},n_{0}\}$ we have
  \begin{equation*}
  |f_{n}(x)-f(x)|\leq |f_{n}(x)-f_{n_{0}}(x)|+|f_{n_{0}}(x)-f(x)|<\frac{\varepsilon}{3}+\frac{\varepsilon}{3}=\frac{2\varepsilon}{3}.
  \end{equation*}
  Hence by taking supremum over all $x\in X$, we have $\|f_{n}-f\|_{\infty}\leq \frac{2\varepsilon}{3}<\varepsilon$ for all $n\geq n_{1}$. Hence $\|f_{n}-f\|_{\infty}\to 0$. You may now either conclude that $f\in C_{b}(X;\mathbb{R})$ since $f$ is the uniform limit of continuous bounded functions, or prove it as follows. Let $x\in X$ and everything else as above remain fixed. Since $f_{n_{1}}$ is continuous, there exists $\delta>0$ so that $f_{n_{1}}B(x,\delta)\subseteq B(f_{n_{1}}(x),\frac{\varepsilon}{3})$. Now for all $y\in B(x,\delta)$ we have
  \begin{align*}
  |f(x)-f(y)| &\leq |f(x)-f_{n_{1}}(x)|+|f_{n_{1}}(x)-f_{n_{1}}(y)|+|f_{n_{1}}(y)-f(y)| \\
  &\leq 2\|f_{n_{1}}-f\|_{\infty}+|f_{n_{1}}(x)-f_{n_{1}}(y)| \\
  &<3\frac{\varepsilon}{3}=\varepsilon,
  \end{align*}
  and thus $fB(x,\delta)\subseteq B(f(x),\varepsilon)$. Hence $f$ is continuous. Finally, since 
  \begin{equation*}
  \|f\|_{\infty}\leq \|f-f_{n_{1}}\|_{\infty}+\|f_{n_{1}}\|_{\infty}<\frac{\varepsilon}{3}+\|f_{n_{1}}\|_{\infty}<\infty,
  \end{equation*}
  then $f$ is bounded. Hence $f\in C_{b}(X;\mathbb{R})$, and since $\|f_{n}-f\|_{\infty}\to 0$, we have proven that $C_{b}(X;\mathbb{R})$ is complete.
- $(ii)$ Note that $|O(x)(y)|=|d(y,x)-d(y,x_{0})|\leq d(x,x_{0})$ for all $y\in X$ by the reverse triangle-inequality. Hence $\|O(x)\|_{\infty}\leq d(x,x_{0})$, which shows that $O(x)$ is bounded for every $x\in X$. The functions $y\mapsto d(y,x)$ and $y\mapsto -d(y,x_{0})$ are continuous, so each $O(x)$ is continuous as a sum of two continuous functions. Hence $O(x)\in C_{b}(X;\mathbb{R})$ for every $x\in X$.
- $(iii)$ Note at first, that again by the reverse triangle-inequality it follows that for all $x,y\in X$:
  \begin{align*}
  \|O(x)-O(y)\|_{\infty}&= \sup_{z\in X}\|O(x)(z)-O(y)(z)\|_{\infty} \\
  &=\sup_{z\in X}\|d(x,z)-d(z,x_{0})-d(z,y)+d(z,x_{0})\|_{\infty} \\
  &=\sup_{z\in X}\|d(x,z)-d(z,y)\|_{\infty} \\
  &\leq d(x,y).
  \end{align*}
  On the other hand, 
  \begin{align*}
  0\leq d(x,y)&=d(x,y)-d(x,x_{0})+d(x,x_{0})-d(x,x) \\
  &=O(y)(x)-O(x)(x) \\
  &= |O(y)(x)-O(x)(x)| \\
  &\leq \|O(y)-O(x)\|_{\infty}.
  \end{align*}
  Hence $\|O(y)-O(x)\|_{\infty}=d(x,y)$ for all $x,y\in X$, which shows that $x\mapsto O(x)$ is an isometric embedding $X\to C_{b}(X;\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: In your first point you show $\lVert f_n- f \rVert < \frac 2 3 \epsilon$ if $n \geq n_1$, which seems strange to me since $n_1$ dependes on a chosen $x \in X$. As I see it, you cannot simply take the supremum if you don't have a uniform $n_0$ which is valid for all $x \in X$.