# Simpler Proof That A Metric Space Is Complete

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I would like to know why the following much simpler proof is not used to answer questions like the following (e.g., see part (i) of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/314001/the-space-of-continuous-bounded-functions-from-a-metric-space-x-to-mathbb-r) or the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71121/space-of-bounded-continuous-functions-is-complete)).

Let $X$ be the set of all bounded functions on $[0,1]$ and let

$$
d(f,g) = \operatorname{sup}_{x\in [0,1] } { |f(x)-g(x)| }
$$

Prove that $(X,d)$ is complete.

I understand and can follow the more complicated proofs (viz., first use the supremum to show pointwise convergence, etc.), but my first attempt at a solution would be the following:

Let $\bar{X}$ be the completion of $X$ and let $\{f_k\}$ be a Cauchy sequence in $X$. Then there exists $f\in \bar{X}$ such that $f_k \rightarrow f$. Thus, given $\epsilon > 0$, there exits $N$ such that $n \geq N$ implies that $d(f_n,f) < \epsilon$. Since $f_n \in X$, we know that $d(f_n,0)<M_n<\infty$, so that

$$
d(f,0)\leq d(f,f_n) + d(f_n,0) < \epsilon + M_n < \infty,
$$

which implies that $f$ is bounded and, hence, $f \in X$, thereby showing that $X$ is complete.

Comment: "which implies that $f$ is bounded"? What does that mean? Remember, $f$ is just an element of the completion of $X$; you have no right to assume it is a function or anything.

Comment: @ChrisEagle So the answer is that $f$ is not necessarily a function? Because if it were, then the above would show it to be bounded, no?

Comment: Yes, so a major first step in your solution should be to show that the limiting element $f$ is a real-valued function on $[0,1]$.

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong Thanks. I can now see why the other proofs include as a first step the establishment of pointwise convergence.

Comment: @ChrisEagle Something is bugging me about the above. How can $f_n \rightarrow f$ and $f$ not be a function? More specifically, the metric takes functions as input, so how could one even assign a value to $d(f,f_n)$ if $f$ were not a function? And would not the same thing apply to any incomplete metric space? If $f$ is in in the completeion of a space and $f_n \rightarrow f$, then $f$ must be of a type such that distance metric makes sense. What am I missing?

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85: Do you know what "completion" actually means?

Comment: @ChrisEagle I suppose not. Don't worry about it then.

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85, The key issue with assuming that $f$ is already a function, is that when we extend $d$ to the completion of the space, who knows how $d$ is defined. Of course, for all the elements of the original metric space, $d$ is defined in the way you gave above. But who is to say that the definition of $d$ outside that space resembles that?